# how do i get a collapsable pane like the netbeans palette

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, panel

i like the style of netbeans palette (Window -> Palette, best seen when creating a gui). i would like to integrate a similar collapsable panel in my application, but i have no idea how to find this component. i guess its not a standard swing component, although it looks kind of similar to a jTree. i poked arround the netbeans framework, but i couldnt find the corresponding class.

I know about swingx's JXTaskPane, but i would really prefer an easy, clean way to hide, show and group ui components, without fancy-animation bloating my app needlessly. The netbeans palette seems just perfect. but how is it called & where can i find it?

Comment: You could use Netbeans platform to build your app, otherwise this question has little to do with netbeans and a lot to do with swing. Tagging the question as swing might get you more answers.